# How many times was Ethereum 2.0 delayed for? When was it suppose to be released initially?

Tags: eth-2.0

Last I recall, Ethereum 2.0 was suppose to be released a few years back. But its always "soon" on the horizon. How many times have it been pushed back? When was the initial date it was suppose to launch?

Wasn't the ice age difficulty mining increase suppose to force Ethereum into 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for you, but maybe a bit more information.

Originally the idea was to switch the whole chain to a Proof of Stake with lots of features - this new chain was called Eth2. I guess this was somewhere around 2017.

Some time after that (very rough guess: 2019) the community realized that it's not feasible to have such a "big bang" switch. Mostly for two reasons: 1) the amount of implementation required was a lot more than anticipated and 2) huge risks in doing such a big bang instead of smaller incremental changes.

In fact, the whole term "Eth2" has been deprecated, around the start of this year. It's too misleading, since we are not switching from version 1 to version 2. Nowadays the plan is to do smaller incremental changes, and the next bigger of these smaller changes is "The Merge", when the network switches to use Proof of Stake. After that, there are still many more improvements coming, related to shards and for example (rollup) data packing. Basically there is no version when it could be said "Eth 2 is now done".

The ice age difficulty bombs were indeed designed to force users out of the Proof of Work network, once the "Eth 2" is ready. I'm not sure if the ice age makes much sense with the current plans, since the network will anyway transition into the new network, but maybe it still helps to get miners to update their nodes faster.

Furthermore, it could be also said that no new version has ever been delayed, since nobody has promised any specific date. Everything has always been an estimate. And there is no central authority who could announce specific dates anyway.